Are there any connecter to connect with firebase | firestore?
Any connector to connect with firestore from ballerina, I couldn't find any in ballerina central can somebody provide me with necessary details on how to connect to firestore.
google cloud firestore connector from ballerina

At the moment there is no official Ballerina connector for Firestore. However there is one published by a third-party developer that offers connectivity to firebase real-time db: https://central.ballerina.io/lakpahana/firebase_realtime_database/latest
You can use it if it satisfies your requirement.
